# how can I improve my Rakefile (deployment)

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm writing my first Rakefile. The first things that I see in the doc is ["there is no special format for a Rakefile"](http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) and "there is no special syntax in a Rakefile".

Ok, so I had to come up with something on my own, but I can see at least two problems with my creature:

**1)** I need to create a number of folders, five of them. The sequence of 6 `directory` tasks looks a bit weird. The list of 5 dependencies in `deploy` task looks even more weird. Can I shrink it down to one line somehow?

**2)** I need to repeat my directory name literals two times - when I define their deployment paths and when I copy the contents. Can I avoid that without introducing 5 more variables?

In Java Ant I would create a properties file with all name literals - can I do that with Rake?

This is what I've got:

```
WEBAPPSDIR = '/var/webapps/'
WEBAPPNAME = 'foo.local'
WEBAPPDIR = File.join(WEBAPPSDIR, WEBAPPNAME)
VIEWSDIR = File.join(WEBAPPDIR, 'views')
PUBLICDIR = File.join(WEBAPPDIR, 'public')
CSSDIR = File.join(PUBLICDIR, 'css')
IMAGESDIR = File.join(PUBLICDIR, 'images')
TMPDIR = File.join(WEBAPPDIR, 'tmp')
HTMLDIR = File.join(PUBLICDIR, 'html')

directory VIEWSDIR
directory CSSDIR
directory HTMLDIR
directory IMAGESDIR
directory TMPDIR

desc 'Deploy to webapps dir'
task :deploy => [VIEWSDIR, CSSDIR, IMAGESDIR, TMPDIR, HTMLDIR] do
  cp 'config.ru', WEBAPPDIR
  Dir.glob('*.rb') {|f| cp f, WEBAPPDIR}
  Dir.glob('views/*.{mab,str}') {|f| cp f, VIEWSDIR}
  Dir.glob('css/*.css') {|f| cp f, CSSDIR}
  Dir.glob('images/*.{png,jpg,gif}') {|f| cp f, IMAGESDIR}
  Dir.glob('html/*.html') {|f| cp f, VIEWSDIR}
end

desc 'Cleans webapp dir'
task :clean do
  rm_r WEBAPPDIR, {force: true}
end
```

Other thoughts/links/examples are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not really answer your question - but why don't you use `capistrano` ? If you don't know it already, it's a ruby tool frequently used to handle deployments smoothly

Comment: will take a look thanks! is it something that you use yourself?

Comment: I used it personally, yes, we use it at my company, and several "big names" (GitHub is the one on the top of my head) are using it, too. It's pretty mainstream in the ruby/rails community

Comment: It says it is used to deploy from SCM to a (remote) server, but can it deploy from local filesystem to local server (just copy)?

Comment: I don't know about this use case. It is an opinionated software, the developers might not care about this situation. For what it's worth though, unless your project is private and you don't want to invest in a private repository hosting service, or don't want to maintain your own, you can setup a repo online pretty quickly

Comment: but development is done on local machines and deployment is done mostly from them - without the need to commit to online repo :) will try to make it work for me, thanks

Comment: Again, it's only my opinion, but setting an online repo is not always necessary, but most of the time, it is convenient. It serves as an online backup, and well, for deployment as well. Hope you'll find something that suits you :)

Comment: I do have a repository. I just don't want to commit to it each time I need to deploy :)